# Get real time updates from a Facebook page I do not own

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get real time updates from a Facebook page that I'm not a owner with Graph API 2.x.?

For example, when the page adds a new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. Only for Pages which use the app:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/subscriptions#publishperms

> Subscriptions for the object type page will only be valid for Pages that have installed the app. You can install the app for a Page using the /{page-id}/subscribed_apps edge.

Comment: what the about the current user ?
I saw there is real time update for user-feed, BUT
with graph 2.x the permission for read_stream is not granted for iOS.

so, what I can do with user-feed updates( if it's possible) without reading those feeds ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Basically nothing imho... Realtime Updates will signal you that there have been changes to the feed, but in order to request the actual change in the user feed you'll need the `read_stream` permission, whcih you likely will not get granted...

Comment: Why facebook so afraid from iOS apps that will show the facebook data in diffrent ways, they could even "force" us to display facebook ads for win-win situation 

sad.
thanks man.

Comment: That's also not really clear to me. I guess it's about the ads as you suggested as well